# How many kinds of properties of field are able to be set in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was confused about mongoose doc. I was trying to understand schema of field. Because the doc explains uncleanly and incompletely, I can't get complete info in  only one page focused on specify introduction.

Currently, I know I can set as following:

```
var exampleSchema = new Schema({
  fieldname:  { type: ...,
                required: ...,
                min: ...<only for number type>,
                max: ...<only for number type>,
                enum: ...<only for string type>,
                match: ...<only for string type>,
                maxlength : ...<only for string type>,
                minlength: ...<only for string type>,
                validate: ...,
              }
  ...
});
```

When I look [models](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) of section, the example code have `size` field as following:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', size: 'string' });
var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', schema);
```

Is it able to be set property? Are there properties I haven't mentioned?

I hope it has a list for explaining total properties, it would make me lookup easily.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but `size` is just an example field name, just like `name` is. It's not a validation attribute.

Comment: @JohnnyHK OMG. If it's example on doc, it should display valid usage. I understand you are confused about my question.

Comment: @JohnnyHK If you know what properties are available in field, please solve my confused, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I catch your question correctly, the `size` is **not** one property as you mentioned, it is the field name, and its type is `string`.

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', size: 'string' });
```

same as

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: {type: String}, size: {type: String} });
```

---

Currently, there are only [8 types](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) in mongoose as below

- String, Number, Date, Buffer, Boolean, Mixed, Objectid, Array

For more properties of [`String` type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema-string-js)

- trim, uppercase, lowercase, minlength, maxlength, match, enum

[`Number` type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema-number-js)

- min, max

[`Date` type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema-date-js)

- min, max, expires

Other schema type properties also could be found in the same page.

Comment: Great! It's my wanted.